# Using function that uses 'this' keyword not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Title may not be correct but i didnt know how to ask my question !
I have encountered a problem with `this` keyword . While using it as in this code `<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"></input>`
it works perfectly. But when i allot a function on input element that uses `this` keyword , it dont work as in
HTML

```
<input type="text" ></input>
```

Javascript

```
var inp=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
inp.onkeyup=up;
function up()
{   
    this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: It seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/9t3er4dv/

Comment: No, it's not working ,that's why i have asked the question @nikhil

Comment: As per the code provided, it is working. You can verify in the fiddle shared. There seems to be some other issue if it is not working.

Comment: @pradeepArora where you add your javascript in page?

Comment: What's the error you are getting? "*it don't work*" is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Can you bind onkeyup event in HTML? If yes then use this code:

```
<script>
function up(element) {   
    element.value = element.value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>
<input type="text" onkeyup="up(this)"></input>
```

Comment: yeah this is working , but can u tell what is the problem with that code ? @keammoort

Answer (score 0):

How about taking it off of the global scope?  Try binding in an IIFE:

```
    (function bindEventHandler(tag) {

        var inp = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];

        inp.onkeyup = function up() {   
            this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();
        };
    }('input'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it this way, make sure to add the script at the end of your body tags, and then it'll work.